# R xts: apply over a rolling window

Tags: r, xts, rollapply

I wish to execute a function `FUN` over a rolling window of `1 year`. My xts has not the same number of points per year. How can I do that in an efficient way?

P.S. usually to execute a `FUN` over a fixed number of datapoints (for instance 100) I use:

```
as.xts(rollapply(data = zoo(indicator), FUN = FUN, width = 100, align = "right"))
```

but obviously this doesn't work if there are not always the same number of points per year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer my own question: One way to do that is:

1. First to NA-pad the time series so that there is one datapoint per day (or any unit relevant for your case),
2. (optional, depending on your FUN) Then to use `na.locf` to carry over the last data to fill the holes.
3. Finally to use the usual rollapply as shown in the question, over a fixed number of datapoints that corresponds to 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the `apply.yearly(x, FUN, ...)` function from the `xts` library.

```
dat <- xts(rnorm(1000), order.by = as.Date(1:1000))
plot(dat)
apply.yearly(dat, mean)
```